# Variables are never assigned a value when called from inside a generic method

Tags: c#, generics, windows-services

I feel like I'm missing something really simple here. Code is as follows:

```
public partial class DatabaseService : ServiceBase
{
    internal static ServiceHost incomingCallServiceHost;
    internal static ServiceHost personServiceHost;

    public DatabaseService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void StartService<TService>(ServiceHost svchost)
    {
        svchost?.Close();
        svchost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TService));
        svchost.Open();
    }

    private void StopService(ServiceHost svchost)
    {
        if (svchost != null)
        {
            svchost.Close();
            svchost = null;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            StartService<IncomingCallService>(incomingCallServiceHost);
            StartService<PersonService>(personServiceHost);
        }
        catch(System.Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
        }           
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        StopService(incomingCallServiceHost);
        StopService(personServiceHost);
    }
}
```

When this code is compiled, there are warnings that the two `ServiceHost` variables are never initialised and will always be null.

The only way I can get the variables to be initialised is by taking the code from the `StartService` method and putting it in the `OnStart` method, which creates duplicated and repetitious code.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        incomingCallServiceHost?.Close();
        incomingCallServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(IncomingCallService));
        incomingCallServiceHost.Open();

        personServiceHost?.Close();
        personServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(PersonService));
        personServiceHost.Open();
    }
    catch(System.Exception ex)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
    }           
}
```

It feels like a generic method should work here but it doesn't. why is this?

Comment: If you want it to work as is - you need to pass by ref: StartService(ref ServiceHost svchost).

Comment: That seems to have fixed it. Could you explain why I need to use the ref keyword?

Comment: Because you assign a new value to svchost parameter inside StartService. Its too long to explain details in comment - just read documentation about ref keyword - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx

Comment: Right, I understand it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have put this earlier but Evk had the right answer. Needed to use the ref keyword on the ServiceHost parameter.